# Creating android app Database with big amount of data

Tags: java, database, android

The database of my application need to be filled with a lot of data,
so during `onCreate()`, it's not only some create table sql
instructions, there is a lot of inserts. The solution I chose is to
store all this instructions in a sql file located in res/raw and which
is loaded with `Resources.openRawResource(id)`.

It works well but I face to encoding issue, I have some accentuated
caharacters in the sql file which appears bad in my application. This
my code to do this:

```
public String getFileContent(Resources resources, int rawId) throws
IOException
  {
    InputStream is = resources.openRawResource(rawId);
    int size = is.available();
    // Read the entire asset into a local byte buffer.
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();
    // Convert the buffer into a string.
    return new String(buffer);
  }

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   try {
        // get file content
        String sqlCode = getFileContent(mCtx.getResources(), R.raw.db_create);
        // execute code
        for (String sqlStatements : sqlCode.split(";"))
        {
            db.execSQL(sqlStatements);
        }

        Log.v("Creating database done.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Should never happen!
            Log.e("Error reading sql file " + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Error executing sql code " + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

The solution I found to avoid this is to load the sql instructions
from a huge `static final String` instead of a file, and all
accentuated characters appear well.

But isn't there a more elegant way to load sql instructions than a big
`static final String` attribute with all sql instructions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
return new String(buffer);
```

You're converting the array of bytes in to a `java.lang.String` but you're not telling Java/Android the encoding to use.  So the bytes for your accented characters aren't being converted correctly as the wrong encoding is being used.

If you use the [`String(byte[],<encoding>)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.lang.String)) constructor you can specify the encoding your file has and your characters will be converted correctly.

Answer (score 4):

The SQL file solution seems perfect, it's just that you need to make sure that the file is saved in utf8 encoding otherwise all the accentuated characters will be lost. If you don't want to change the file's encoding then you need to pass an extra argument to new `String(bytes, charset)` defining the file's encoding.

Do prefer to use file resources instead of static final String to avoid having all those unnecessary bytes loaded into memory. In mobile phones you want to save all memory possible!

Answer (score 1):

I am using a different approach:
Instead of executing loads of sql statements (which will take long time to complete), I build my sqlite database on the desktop, put it in the assets folder, create an empty sqlite db in android and copy the db from the assets folder into the database folder. This is a huge increase in speed. Note, you need to create an empty database first in android, and then you can copy and overwrite it. Otherwise, Android will not allow you to write a db into the datbase folder. There are several examples on the internet.
BTW, seems this approach works best, if the db has no file extension.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are passing all your sql statements in one string. That's a problem because execSQL expects "a single statement that is not a query" (see documentation [here][1]). Following is a somewhat-ugly-but-working solution.

I have all my sql statements in a file like this:

> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 2, 3);
>
> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (4, 5, 6);
>
> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (7, 8, 9);

Notice the new lines in between text(semicolon followed by 2 new lines)
Then, I do this:

```
String text = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
for (String command : text.split(";\n\n")) { 
   try { command = command.trim(); 
   //Log.d(TAG, "command: " + command); 
   if (command.length() > 0) 
      db.execSQL(command.trim()); 
}
catch(Exception e) {do whatever you need here}
```

My data columns contain blobs of text with new lines AND semicolons, so I had to find a different command-separator. Just be sure to get creative with the split str: use something you know doesn't exist in your data.

HTH
Gerardo

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[])

Comment: I do a split(";") too, and my problem wasn't about sql statements but encoding characters.